# Using SVG image as curve profile in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves, svg

I have a question regarding curve profiles in Geometry Nodes.
Does anyone know if it is possible to use an SVG image profile directly as a curve profile in Geometry Nodes? (The SVG is already imported as curve)
I know it's easy to select an object in the curve settings in the geometry area, which can be an imported SVG object, among other things.
But is there also a way using only Geometry Nodes?
Thank you for your support

Comment: You can't open files within geometry nodes. There's no such functionality.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, - of course the SVG is already imported as curve object in the blend file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Curve to Mesh" allows you to specify a profile curve, and you can use an external object's data for that:

[image]

You have to import the SVG and eventually process it in a destructive way, outside of geonodes, as there's no file opening capability in GN.

Comment: Hi again & thanks it works.  I´m not quite sure, but it seems that the Data Panel interpret the "Object" link different as the "Object Info" Node in GN. But the difference is minimal - so thx again.

Answer (score 1):

In the "Properties > Data" panel you need to make sure that the "Fill Mode" is set to *None*:

[image: the "Properties > Data" panel]

It is set to *Both* by default for imported SVG curves.